# On $routeChangeStart loads controller issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am navigating one page to another page in angular , when i in second page on click on back button i am returning to first page for this i used $routeChangeStart, This will loading my controller once again , How to avoid this one ,
Here is my code .

```
homepal.run(function run($http, $cookies,$rootScope,$location){
    $rootScope.contactwdgt="contact-wdgt";
    $rootScope.header=true;
    $rootScope.homepage=true;
    $rootScope.innerHeader="";
    $rootScope.filter=false;

});
```

And in my index.html

```
<div ng-if="homepage" ng-include src="'template/homepage.html'"></div>
```

Now my  $routeChangeStart ,

```
a.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(scope, next, current) {

        b.homepage = true;
        b.innerHeader = "";
        b.searchFilter = false;

        srchCls_Element.removeClass('listing-navbar');

    });
```

Whenever root changes my home page loads first then second page(till response comes till will show home page only.)

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to stop the controller loading again when it's being reloaded again via navigation.. Are you talking about caching ?

Comment: b.homepage = true; is making load home page first then after response  then second page